# What will be the xpath for below expression

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <span class="dijitArrowNodeInner" data-dojo-attach-point="arrowNodeInner"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="dijitTitlePaneTextNode" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <div>Scripts</div>
        </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

What will be the xpath for the above expression to get the 'Script'.

Comment: Do you mean 'Scripts', within the `<div>Scripts</div>` ?

Answer (score 2):

If by "the Script" you mean the text content of the inner `div` element:

```
/tr/td/div/div
```

Else, if you mean the `div` element that has "Scripts" as its content:

```
//div[. = 'Scripts']
```

But I doubt this is of much help unless you explain exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample provided, this should work:

`//tr/td/div[@class='dijitTitlePaneTextNode']/div[text()]`